# Elements are disappearing while changing a list into set

Tags: python, python-3.7

While I am changing a list to set.I am getting this kind of behavior:

```
>>> set([1,"False",False,True])
{False, 1, 'False'}
>>> set([True,"orange",1])
{True, 'orange'}
```

In first case, True is missing and in second, 1 is missing. Is this because of some kind of data loss due to type conversion? Or am I missing something here?
The IDLE I am using is 3.7.9 . I have attached a screenshot if that might be helpful.[screenshot of python REPL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4n13.png)

Comment: In python `True == 1`

Answer (score 1):

`set` only contains unique items, and 1 is coerced to True, this is why the second True item disappears